# Combine two eloquent relationships in a single Model and combine their data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table, relationship

I have multiple eloquent relationships set up through the backend in a laravel application.  I need to sort of combine a few of them in a return and I'm not sure how to go about it.  I'm considering a hasManyThrough relationship but I feel like since I get the data I need through other relational calls there is probably some way to combine the two.  Anyways here are my call in my Quote model.

```
/**
 * The items that belong to the quote.
 */
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item')->withPivot('waste', 'subtotal', 'required');
}

/**
 * The categories that have been added to a quote.
 */
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withPivot('priority', 'expanded')->with('items');
}
```

What I'd like to do is somehow combine these two relationships so that categories() returns everythign that it does but it attaches the pivot table from the items method to the eager load items.  I don't quite konw if I've explained it properly but I hope so.

Comment: What does the database structure look like? Is there a relationship between categories and items?

Comment: Why can't you just do `Quote::with(['categories', 'items'])->get()`?

Comment: sorry for the delay guys I have been out of town.  Categories have many items and items have one category.